# Can Twinned Spell affect Chain Lightning?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic

The Twinned Spell effect works on spells that target a single person, so would it work with Chain Lightning, which only hits a single target in the start, but slowly spreads?

Comment: Related: [How does the Chain Lightning spell target?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55819)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Twinned Spell says:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature [...]

With the release of the [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) for the PHB, we have this additional restriction:

> To be eligible
>   for Twinned Spell, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one creature at
>   the spell’s current level.

And *Chain Lightning* says:

> You create a bolt of lightning that arcs toward a target of your choice that you can see within range. Three bolts then leap from that target to as many as **three other targets**.

So no, you can't use Twinned Spell on *Chain Lightning*. *Chain Lightning* targets up to four creatures, and Twinned Spell requires the spell to only be capable of targeting one.

If a further argument is required, [Jeremy Crawford says](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/11/11/is-it-possible-to-twin-spell-chain-lightning/) that Twinned Spell cannot be used on *Chain Lightning*.

Answer (score 9):

## No.

Even though the caster targets only one creature/object, the *spell* targets up to four creatures. Therefore, Twinned Spell can't affect Chain Lightning.