# Is it impossible to Ready the Green-Flame Blade cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, readied-action

I've noticed a curious quirk of wording when it comes to the [*Green-Flame Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) cantrip (SCAG, p. 143). Specifically, this tidbit:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails.

Suppose I want to use my action to Ready a cast of *Green-Flame Blade*. The thing is, [Readying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) a spell is described as casting it using your action, then holding it until you deliver it with your reaction. I haven't struck an enemy with a melee attack as part of the casting so... does it fail, and thus prove itself impossible to Ready?

Answer (score 32):

### This has been fixed in the SCAG errata and TCE reprint

*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* includes an updated version *green-flame blade*. SCAG received an [errata](https://dnd.wizards.com/dndstudioblog/sage-advice-book-updates) when TCE released, which updates it to match the TCE version. The new version of the spell begins:

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell's casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you. On a hit, [...]

The description no longer requires that you make an attack as part of the action you use to cast the spell. Instead, making an attack is one of the spell's effects. **Readying *green-flame blade* is no longer an issue.**

Answer (score 20):

### According to the Lead Game Designer, you can ready the spell

Jeremy Crawford, lead game designer, has mentioned this scenario in an unofficial ruling ([a tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/973777196526415872)):

> You can ready any spell that has a casting time of 1 action. None of the spell's effects, including those of green-flame blade and booming blade, occur until you release the spell.

Upon being asked specifically about the "as part of the action used to cast this spell" phrase he replied:

> Those spells are oddballs.

This is only an example of how the rules were intended to function and not the Rules As Written.

### Rules As Written there is no reason to ready the spell

Technically you *can* ready it, it is a spell with a casting time of 1 action, but this spell includes the phrase:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails.

The action used to cast the spell is indeed the Ready action. But the ready action states:

> [...] When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs [...]

Thus we know that this readying the spell counts as casting the spell, you simply haven't released it yet. This means you **have to make the melee attack when you ready the spell.** However, we also know that a spell's effects cannot occur until you release the spell. This leaves us with two interpretations:

1. Making the attack *is* an effect of the spell and thus we can't even do that.
2. Making the attack is *not* an effect of the spell but the bonus damage and whatnot are. This means we would be holding the spell but nothing would happen if we released it (using our reaction). This is because the later effects of the spell **only apply when you hit**, but that has already happened, so releasing the spell won't do anything.

In either case **there is no reason to ready this spell.**

Comment: Can you support this outside of the unofficial tweet?

Comment: @NautArch honestly no, it's pretty clear to me that RAW you *have to* make the attack when you take the *action* that involves the spell, not a reaction

Comment: Is the "action you use to cast the spell" the Ready action, or is it the reaction? (For context, if you tried to cast it with a bonus action via Quickened Spell, the "action you use to cast the spell" would be the bonus action, I'd think.)

Comment: @MarkWells I don't think it makes a difference. "Readying a spell" means using your Action to cast the spell, but using Concentration to hold the effects of the spell until you use your Reaction to release them. So regardless, the "Casting" of the spell occurs with the initial Action or—if your DM houserules that Bonus Action spells can be readied—Bonus Action.

Comment: Action economy is murky here... there is the Cast a Spell action and the Ready action. As part of the Ready action you can cast a spell for later use with special rules.

Comment: @markwells It does t matter as Xirema pointed out. You aren't using your reaction to cast the spell because the spell is literally cast when you ready it. The description of the ready action says so

Comment: @slagmoth Yes but here we know that the ready action explicitly casts the spell

Comment: For RAI, it may be worth referring to https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87657/can-a-spell-be-readied-to-trigger-when-its-intended-target-comes-into-view.  This answer highlights the ambiguity over whether targeting is a part of casting or releasing the spell and is relevant to this spell, i.e. making the melee attack against the target.

Comment: Why does having hit in the past matter in terms of the effects happening?  It doesn't say "if you hit" or similar...  It seems like readying the spell would let you hold on to the extra damage until later if the attack is not part of the effects, and then decide at some later point that you retroactively did damage to the target in the past, with your interpretations.  That seems useful for control, if a bit niche.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil "On a hit, the target suffers the attack's normal effects, and green fire leaps from the target to a different creature of your choice that you can see within 5 feet of it." None of this can occur anymore because the opportunity "on a hit" has passed. You hit them, and then, even a whole turn later, are trying to activate something that only activates *when* you hit them, which would have been in the past, meaning you can't do it